# Upload file from iOS app to single dropbox account

Tags: ios, upload, sdk, cloud, dropbox

Am I correct in thinking that there is NO api that will enable users of my app to upload a file from their app to my dropbox account? It looks to me that Dropbox wants their app installed (not possible for me) or will show the user a login screen to enable them to log into only THEIR dropbox account.

Answer (score 1):

***I don't think that is possible , as it is clearly stated :***

`[DBSession linkFromController:]` method asks the user to authorize the app,then linking process will switch to the Dropbox mobile app if it's installed  then the user doesn't need to log in again and it will configure owner's A/C and authroze it with the app.

**Just  workaround idea, which may help you someway or other:**

What about using [iOS Chooser SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/ios),through this user can choose a file and share the link of the file directly with other users.Once user successfully chooses the file it redirect back to app and provides a response which contain the following:

> Chooser can be configured to return one of two link types.
>
> **DBChooserLinkTypePreviewlinks** are the default type of link returned by
>   the Chooser. Preview links point to a human-friendly preview page of a
>   file and are great for sharing. You can read more about links to
>   Dropbox files in our Help Center. Note that users may disable this
>   link at a later point if they choose.
>
> **DBChooserLinkTypeDirectlinks** point directly to the contents of the
>   file and are useful for downloading the file itself. Unlike preview
>   links, however, they will expire after four hours, so make sure to
>   download the contents of the file immediately after the file is
>   chosen. These URLs should not be used to display content directly in
>   the browser.